# No MongoDB, como buscar por documentos pelo tamanho de um Array

Tags: array, algoritmo-de-busca, mongodb

Eu tenho uma coleção de documentos que são nós de um grafo, onde cada nó tem sua lista de adjacências:

```
{
'_id': ObjectId('547ce6f4ffaba82f360fc525'),
'adj': ['no_2'],
'nome': 'no_1'
}
{
'_id': ObjectId('547ce6f4ffaba82f360fc526'),
'adj': ['no_1', 'no_3'],
'nome': 'no_2'
}
{
'_id': ObjectId('547ce6f4ffaba82f360fc527'),
'adj': ['no_1'],
'nome': 'no_3'
}
```

Eu quero a lista de todos os documentos (nós) onde o tamanho do array 'adj' seja maior ou igual a um valor X.

Tentei resolver usando **$gt** e **$size** mas tanto o operador **$size** só retorna por valor exato, quando não parece ser possível utilizar os dois operadores em conjunto.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Encontrei uma solução utilizando o **$where**:

```
db.grafo.find( { $where: "this.adj.length > X" } );
```

O problema desta solução é que esta estratégia não faz uso de índices ou qualquer outra estratégia de tornar a busca eficiente: o operador **$where** basicamente executa o operador para todos os documentos da coleção.

(2) Uma segunda estratégia com mais "cara de NoSQL" é criar um novo campo que armazena o tamanho do array. Desta forma dá pra indexar o valor, mas é mais um valor pra se atualizar quando o array for modificado.

(3) Uma terceira solução bem interessante: perguntar se uma determinada posição do array existe!

```
Y=X-1
db.grafo.find( { "adj.Y" : {"$exists": true} } );
```

OBS.1: Só não saberia dizer se existe alguma diferença de eficiência entre (1) e (3). Parece-me que não.

OBS.2: Tanto a solução (1) quanto a (3) só são possíveis no Mongo 2.2+

Comment: A solução (1) usa uma query interpretada em todos os documentos da collection, então ela provavelmente vai ser muito mais lenta do que a solução (3), que é a mais recomendada. Já usei a solução (3) em produção, sem problemas. É uma prática comum.